# Is it possible to use the Azure Offline Sync with .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-mobile-services

We're working on a project with a backend in .Net Core. We're going to add a Xamarin app for Android, and we'd like to use the offline sync technologie Azure offers. Is this possible with a .Net Core API?

Comment: I find a [similar thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2cb8247d-6e16-4596-a90d-710e9340984a/offline-sync-with-api?forum=azuremobile) on MSDN. It mentioned that no, as Azure Mobile Apps is a specific SDK for syncing a SQL Server table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like Azure Mobile Apps Server SDK is not yet supported for .Net Core.

Check out these threads:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/issues/214
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/issues/215
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/issues/210

We are also still waiting for this. I hope they support it soon!